# Keep getting &lt; and &gt XML response on postman

Tags: c#, xml

`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()` does not help with this.

Here is my code:

```cs
string jsonResponse = "{\"methodresponse\":{\"@name\":\"login\",\"@timestamp\":\"2021 / 04 / 20 07:49:12.295\",\"result\":{\"@seq\":\"\",\"@errorcode\":6000,\"@errordescription\":\"Unspecified error\",\"extinfo\":null}}}";

XNode responseXml = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(jsonResponse, "pkt");
return Content(httpStatusCode, HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(responseXml.ToString()), Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

Expected response result:

```xml
<pkt>
 <methodresponse name="login" timestamp="2021/04/20 07:55:36.565" >
 <result seq=""
 errorcode="6000"
 errordescription="Unspecified error">
 <extinfo/>
 </result>
 </methodresponse>
</pkt>
```

Here is postman actual response XML body:

```xml
<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">&lt;pkt&gt;
  &lt;methodresponse name="login" timestamp="2021/04/20 07:55:36.565"&gt;
    &lt;result seq="" errorcode="6000" errordescription="Unspecified error"&gt;
      &lt;extinfo /&gt;
    &lt;/result&gt;
  &lt;/methodresponse&gt;
&lt;/pkt&gt;</string>
```

Comment: You are returning `responseXml.ToString()`. It's a string. So it is returned as such. Because you are wrapping that string in an XML, any special characters in the string have to be escaped, so they are.

Comment: The XML is embedded in a HTTP Response so use following to decode : System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string)

Answer (score 0):

So I parsed the `responseXml` from `XNode` to `XElement` and it works. But I'm not sure if there are more efficient way to do this.

Here is my code:

```
responseXml = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(jsonResponse, "pkt");
XElement xlm = XElement.Parse(responseXml.ToString());
return Content(httpStatusCode, xlm, Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

Comment: `more efficient way to do this` - well, you have an XML in `responseXml`, then you turn it to a string, then you parse it back to XML.

Comment: As above - `Content(httpStatusCode, responseXml, Formatters.XmlFormatter)` would do the same. There's no need to convert it to a string and re-parse it again.